# How to output data to a file as in the example

Tags: c++

I have a problem in the program, which is related to the fact that I have the first line constantly moves off at different distances
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9a7fo.png)
My program code

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <fstream> 
#include <iomanip> 
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std; 
 
struct HouseholdAppliance { 
    string name; 
    string brand; 
    int power;  
    float price;  
    int quantity;  
}; 
 
int main() { 
    HouseholdAppliance appliances[14] = { 
        {"Холодильник", "Samsung", 300, 800, 10}, 
        {"Пылесос", "Dyson", 1500, 400, 8}, 
        {"Микроволновка", "Panasonic", 800, 200, 15}, 
        {"Тостер", "Bosch", 700, 100, 12}, 
        {"Фен", "Philips", 1200, 50, 20}, 
        {"Чайник", "Russell Hobbs", 1500, 30, 18}, 
        {"Стиральная машина", "LG", 2000, 900, 5}, 
        {"Посудомоечная машина", "Siemens", 1800, 1200, 7}, 
        {"Утюг", "Rowenta", 2000, 70, 25}, 
        {"Телевизор", "Sony", 100, 1200, 10}, 
        {"Кофеварка", "Krups", 900, 150, 15}, 
        {"Монитор", "Samsung", 50, 250, 7}, 
        {"Миксер", "Samsung", 600, 80, 10}, 
        {"Микрофон", "Samsung", 10, 120, 15}
    }; 
 
    ofstream outputFile("appliances.txt"); 
 
    if (outputFile.is_open()) { 
        
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) { 
            for (int j = 0; j < (sizeof(appliances)/sizeof(*appliances)); j++) { 
                switch (i) { 
                    case 0: 
                        outputFile << setw(31) << left << appliances[j].name;
                        break; 
                    case 1: 
                        outputFile << setw(20) << left << appliances[j].brand; 
                        break; 
                    case 2: 
                        outputFile << setw(20) << left << appliances[j].power; 
                        break; 
                    case 3: 
                        outputFile << setw(20) << left << appliances[j].price; 
                        break; 
                    case 4: 
                        outputFile << setw(20) << left << appliances[j].quantity; 
                        break; 
                } 
            } 
            outputFile << "\n"; 
        } 
 
        outputFile.close(); 
        cout << "Файл успешно создан." << endl; 
    } else { 
        cout << "Не удалось создать файл." << endl; 
    } 
 
    return 0; 
}
```

The conclusion must be:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QaXW3.png)

All columns should be displayed as shown in the picture above.

Any of the following methods did not get me to the result I wanted.
I tried determining the maximum word length and using that length in setw().
I tried setting setw(50).
I tried using a special function: "outputFile << left << setw(30) << appliances[j].name.substr(0, 30);"
But I still get the same result - the first line is shrunk randomly.

Comment: Examine the `.size()` of each name. They are not what you're assuming them to be.

Comment: With utf-8 the number of characters you see and the actual number of bytes in a string won't always match, and the padding done with `setw` is based on the number of bytes output so it isn't reliable. Here's an example that compensates for that difference to align the columns. https://godbolt.org/z/WPE37EP5z It may work for this simple case but you should research how utf-8 works so you understand it for anything more complicated.